# Are questions about interactions with groups of triggers interacting with the same card acceptable?

Tags: discussion, magic-the-gathering

A new card has been (or will be) printed in m14, Strionic Resonator, which copies triggered abilities. This has massive potential for confusing people by copying quite complicated triggered abilities that will feel like a bit of a minefield without any real one size fits all answer (at least, in my opinion)

for example, with miracle triggers (which I have already asked about [in this question](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/12359/what-happens-when-a-miracle-trigger-is-copied)) I believe the answer to be essentially "nothing happens", but this differs from the answer for transform triggers from the same block (innistrad), wherein I believe the creature should transform and then transform back.

I am sure there are plenty of other confusing situations where different things might happen. **Are seperate questions for these iterations on the same theme acceptable?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say to go ahead and ask any questions you have.

Whatever the answer to your meta question turns out to me, it isn't generally binding on the folks who would be voting to close on the main site.

Ask away, see what happens and I suspect everything will turn out OK.

Comment: ask away is what i have done! thanks